# Cannot use "get" function to load site after opening chrome with active profile on Chrome with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am sucesfully able to load my chrome profile using the flags:
`user-data-dir` as well as `profile-directory`, yet once the profile is loaded and the chrome window is actually open, no webpage appears. It simply gets stuck on a blank screen.

When I remove the code for the profile it is actually able to open the webpage stored in the `login-url` variable.

Tried updating to latest version of chrome (94.0.4606.81) and I also used the exact steps listed [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) to ensure I have the right chrome driver version.

I also did the obvious like making sure there are not any instances of chrome running in the background.

Code is as follows:

```
import os
from os.path import exists
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

headless = False
login_url = "https://google.com)"

def startChrome():
    global headless
    try:
        chrome_options = Options()
        if headless:
            chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("----user-data-dir=C:/Users/ERIK/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")    

        global driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(path+"/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
    except:
        print("Failed to start Chrome!")
        input()
        exit()

startChrome()

driver.get(login_url)
input()
```

Comment: there's a typo there... login_url = "https://google.com)"  could be messing with the url validation.

Answer (score 0):

The following successfully opens google.com for me.

Selenium Version `3.141.0`

ChromeDriver Version `94.0.4606.61`

Chrome Version `94.0.4606.71`

```
from os import path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def getDriver(profile_directory, headless = False):
    chrome_options = Options()
    if headless:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    userDataDir = path.expandvars(r"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userDataDir}")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={profile_directory}")

    return webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

driver = getDriver("Profile 2")
driver.get("https://google.com")
```